# Datastax Solr Search so It Will Results Only 1 Result for Every Range of Date

Tags: cassandra, solr, datastax, dse

I am using Datastax Enterprice 6.8;

I have a trajectory dataset with `timestamp` Date field. This dataset updated at least in every 5 seconds, so it will be 720 data in an hour, for every entity.

Is it possible to do query `search all data of id 'x' between range 'start-date' to 'end-date', but please only give me 1 data for every hour` to get better performance?

Hope my question clear, and every help appreciated.